# Is there a way to change the Iframe width vor the mobile and desktop view?

Tags: html, css, iframe, media-queries

I'm trying to style the iframe on my site with media query. Since the loaded form from the iframe is responsive and looks good in the desktop view, but it looks bad in the mobile view.

If I set the iframe tag width directly to 700 it looks good on the desktop but doesn't fit on the mobile view.

```
<iframe src="....." frameborder="0" width="700" height="950">Your browser does not support embedded frames (iframes) <a href="...." target="_blank">further</a></iframe>
```

Update from my CSS:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  body {
    background-color: blue;
  }

 iframe {
   width: 700px;
 }
}
```

Best regards

Comment: You can use css like "iframe{width: 400px}" in media query.

Comment: @IshitaRay Thank you! I try that know

Comment: Please show us your css code and give a screenshot how it looks like...

Comment: Then you can set two iframe one for mobile and one for desktop. In the media query you write css only display none or block.

Comment: I try to solve now css problem... bc i have a lot css files in my project.

Comment: @IshitaRay I found the issue and solved it! I created a answer to my question below.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/222586/discussion-between-blackplan-and-ishita-ray).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found a solution for my problem.

I changed the iframe tag from

```
<iframe src="....." frameborder="0" width="700" height="950">Your browser does not support embedded frames (iframes) <a href="...." target="_blank">further</a></iframe>
```

to

```
<iframe src="....." frameborder="0" width="100%" height="950">Your browser does not support embedded frames (iframes) <a href="...." target="_blank">further</a></iframe>
```

The only thing I needed to change was just **width 100%**. The iframe is with the 100% now responsive and has also a nice mobile view beside the desktop view.

Answer (score 4):

Did you wrote this tag?

`<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">`

Comment: Hey @Sherzod, I wrote this tag.